# Android Gesture recognition

Tags: android

What algorithm is used in Android Gesture recognition?Can I get the source code anywhere?
I will be using android gestures recognition feature and I need to know what are the basic requirements or criteria for Gesture recognition?How does it **predict** a score against matching gestures?**Does it depend on number of gesture strokes?? or the size of gesture strokes?**

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the Android Api Source code

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/services/java/com/android/server/accessibility/TouchExplorer.java

Answer (score 0):

You can use IBM Wearables SDK for Android
it allows you to record gestures and then recognise them in your app

for more info:
https://github.com/ibm-wearables-sdk-for-mobile/ibm-wearables-android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how exactly it works since I haven't tried understanding the code and not sure if I'm capable at my current skill level. But to get the code in androidStudio (don't know if you are using that but maybe it's similar in other software?).

Create a GestureDetector:

```
private GestureDetector mDetector;
```

Select the GestureDetector, right click and goto Declaration (CTRL+B).
It takes you to the code. Inside that code you can also select methods and right click go to their declaration.
If it shows you that you don't have the code, I think something pops up to install it. If not you can install it like this:

Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager. In the tab SDK Platforms click on show package details below. Select sources you want to install. You can install sources for multiple versions so you can also check code of older versions if you'd want to.

You can also directly check the files on your computer, the path is something like this for example (if on windows):
C:\Users\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-22\android\view <-here is for example view code for android api level 22